# Change Specific Layout on Android Studio

Tags: android

I just wanted to ask if this is possible in android studio

[image]

As you can see I pointed out the blue area that I needed to change after I pressed the `Send Profile` button . Change I mean is that I can hide or something like that the `fullname,address,phonenumber,emailaddress` etc because I wanted to add some more forms to fill up.

Thank you if someone can direct me to a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a fragment place holder for the outlined blue area, and do fragment transitions as you want to go.

Each form can be represented by a separate xml layout file that you can place in this place holder.

Comment: hmmm can I create a fragment programmatically and by not adding new fragment by right clicking something like that?

Comment: sure you can do that, you need a `FragmentTransaction` instance that you can call `.repace()` or `.add()`.. please have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122570/replace-a-fragment-programmatically)

Comment: but as far as I can understand fragment the whole page will be replaced right ? I just wanted the blue area to be replace by another forms to be fill up

Comment: It's up to you if you want to replace the entire area of the activity or just a certain area, Doc quote: `You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities.`

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you are using something like a Constraintlayout you can just reference the views and set their visibility to View.GONE
So you would put that into the onClickListener of the Button (after validating perhaps) and then you could hide those views.

You can also use fragments but those might be hard for a beginner (which I assume you are) so instead for replacing those views you might be able to just use a mix of setting titles/hints of textfields to something different and hiding views (or showing new ones).

LinearLayout would also make this easy because views are just ontop of one another like in your case (only the blue area) so hiding/showing is straight forward.

Comment: Yes I am new to android studio actually. But the fragment in not a bad idea tho cause i've got a bit of experience on it. Thank you

Comment: No problem, appreciate the like.

Comment: There's actually a problem on a fragment because I don't need to replace the whole page . I just need the specific space/area to be changed

Comment: Well... it might be hard because getting Fragments working (especially clean) in this case really isn't something I'd recommend for beginners. Full Screen fragments yeah, but blue box only seems harder than it should be in your case perhaps

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be putting another LinearLayout there, and all those other elements into this new LinearLayout. Then you can just use

```
findViewById(R.id.yourNewLinearLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide all those things.

Comment: so does my other forms will go up automatically if I set my first LinearLayout to invisible?

Comment: If you set it to View.INVISIBLE, then no, but with View.GONE they will. If you want the 'Send profile' button to stay at the bottom, you could try putting an empty element before it with height=0dp.